# How can i invoke signalr call from another view controller ios?

Tags: ios

**Decisioncontroller.m**

```
-(void)signalrcall:(NSArray *)vals {
    [chat1 invoke:@"SendPrivateMessage" withArgs:vals];
}
```

**chatcontroller.m**

```
Decisioncontroller *dec=[[Decisioncontroller alloc]init];
[dec signalrcall:val];
```

no response from server.

Comment: Is your function being called in `Decisioncontroller `?

Comment: from chat controller

Comment: - (IBAction)send:(id)sender 
{
     if(_chatTxt.text.length !=0)
    {
        [val addObject:_chatTxt.text];
        [dec signalrcall:val];
        [_chattable reloadData];
    }
}

Comment: but what is your problem? you say `no response from server.` So is your function not called in `Decisioncontroller` or `[chat1 invoke:@"SendPrivateMessage" withArgs:vals];` does not post `vals` to the server?

Comment: Function called in Decisioncontroller, but [chat1 invoke:@"SendPrivateMessage" withArgs:vals]; does not post any call to the server.

Comment: well, than paste code what should post the message to the server.

Comment: I have tried with 'NSLog(@"%@",vals);'. I am getting message whatever I sent. I put breakpoint in server side, but it was not hit.